# parsing csv file in python and csv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to parse a csv file but it seems that I'm missing something basic and can't get it right. Each raw of the csv contains a string in {} including several parameters randomly sorted such as in the example below.

```
Timestamp,Session Index,Event,Description,Version,Platform,Device,User ID,Params,
"Dec 03, 2014 01:30 AM",1,NoRegister,,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{},
"Dec 03, 2014 01:30 AM",2,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{ UserID : 36875; tabName : QuickAndEasy},
"Dec 03, 2014 01:30 AM",3,UserRecipeOverview,How many users go to Overview of a recipe?,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{ RecipeID : 1488;  UserID : 36875},
```

My code is the following but I get an error that I don't understand:

```
counter = 0

mappedLines = {}

import csv
with open ('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader (f)

    for line in reader:
        counter = counter + 1
        lineDict = {}
        line = line.replace("{","")
        line = line.replace("}","")
        line = line.strip()
        fieldPairs = line.split(";")

        for pair in fieldPairs:
            fields = pair.split(":")
            key = fields[0].strip()
            value = fields[1].strip()
            lineDict[key] = value

        mappedLines[counter] = lineDict

def printFields(keys, lineSets):
    output_line = ""
    for key in keys:
       if key in lineSets:
           output_line = output_line + lineSets[key] + ","
       else:
           output_line += ","
    print output_line[0:len(output_line) - 1]

fields = ["UserID", "tabName", "RecipeID", "type", "searchWord", "isFromLabel"]

for key in range(1,len(mappedLines) + 1):
    lineSets = mappedLines[key]
    printFields(fields,lineSets)
```

Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "testV3.py", line 14, in <module>
      line = line.replace("{","")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

EDIT:

I'm now triyng to include the write function to save the output to a new csv file with the following. the csv record the headers only and in column.

```
import csv


def printfields(keys, linesets):
    output_line = ""
    for key in keys:
        if key in linesets:
            output_line += linesets[key] + ","
        else:
            output_line += ","
    print output_line


def csv_writer(reader, path):
    """
    write reader to a csv file path
    """
    with open(path, "wd") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        for line1 in line:
            if line1 in path
            writer.writerow(line1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fields = [
        "UserID", "tabName", "RecipeID", "type", "searchWord", "isFromLabel", "targetUID"
    ]
    mappedLines = {}
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in reader:
            fieldPairs = [
                p for p in
                line['Params'].strip().strip('}').strip('{').strip().split(';')
                if p
            ]
            lineDict = {
                pair.split()[0].strip(): pair.split(':')[1].strip()
                for pair in fieldPairs
            }
            mappedLines[reader.line_num] = lineDict
        path = "output.csv"
        csv_writer(reader, path)

    for key in sorted(mappedLines.keys()):
        linesets = mappedLines[key]
        printfields(fields, linesets)
```

Comment: I have solved your original question and imho your EDIT qualifies as a standalone question. If you agree, would you move your additional edit part of your question into a new question and resolved this question as answered?

Comment: Hi @dopstar, Thanks for your help, comments and recommendations when using Stack overflow. As you probably noticed I'm still learning good practices when getting help from the community. your Help helps a lot! I have now created a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815100/parsing-and-saving-csv-file-in-python-and-csv-module including my edits so you can answer it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rearranged your code and modified it. The changes are that it uses `csv.DictReader`, and counter variable is no longer used. and the `range` function in the for loop is no longer used.

```
import csv


def printFields(keys, lineSets):
    output_line = ""
    for key in keys:
        if key in lineSets:
            output_line += lineSets[key] + ","
        else:
            output_line += ","
    print output_line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fields = [
        "UserID", "tabName", "RecipeID", "type", "searchWord", "isFromLabel"
    ]
    mappedLines = {}
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in reader:
            fieldPairs = [
                p for p in
                line['Params'].strip().strip('}').strip('{').strip().split(';')
                if p
            ]
            lineDict = {
                pair.split()[0].strip(): pair.split(':')[1].strip()
                for pair in fieldPairs
            }
            mappedLines[reader.line_num] = lineDict

    for key in sorted(mappedLines.keys()):
        lineSets = mappedLines[key]
        printFields(fields, lineSets)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. still struggling to write the output to a csv file though

Comment: So now I'm trying to write the ouptupt to a csv file but I only get the headers in the csv file

Comment: Would you then upvote this answer as useful at the very least and thereafter create a separate question for your additional part?

Comment: I think I've done what you suggested. let me know if not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`line` is a list containing the cells of the current row. To access one of them, use a loop:

```
for cell in line:
    cell.replace(...)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your feedback but I'm sorry I still don't get it. I already use a loop and I don't know what to do with yours. Could you explain more and detail how I should add/replace another loop? Tks! M.

Comment: As I wrote: `line` is an array, not a string. You can't use `replace` on it. If you want to change the cell content, you must use *two* loops: one for the rows, and one for the cells in a row.

Comment: @mmarboeuf: `line[8]` is the only cell/field with the `{` and `}` characters in it -- so you could also do something like `line[8].replace(...)` rather than loop over each of them.

Comment: That should be `cell.replace` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statement to remove the "{" and "}" in a list of string

```
line = ".".join(line).replace("{","").replace("}","").split(",")
```

Comment: Why parse the file as CSV when you then lump all the cells together again?