# parsing and saving csv file in python and csv module

Tags: python, parsing, csv

This script is meant to parse and sort a list from a csv file and save to a newly created csv file, including headers.

I triyng to include the write function to save the output of this parser to a new csv file with the following. This code create a csv but record the headers only and in one column.

Here's the input:

```
Timestamp,Session Index,Event,Description,Version,Platform,Device,User ID,Params,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:26 AM",1,NoRegister,,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5c (GSM),,{},
"Dec 27, 2014 05:24 AM",1,NoRegister,,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5c (GSM),,{},
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",1,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{ UserID : 54807;  tabName : Home},
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",2,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{ UserID : 54807;  tabName : Home},
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",3,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),,{ UserID : 54807;  tabName : QuickAndEasy},
```

Here's the output I'd like to get saved to csv:

```
Timestamp,Session Index,Event,Description,Version,Platform,Device,User ID,TabName,RecipeID,Type,SearchWord,IsFromLabel,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:26 AM",1,NoRegister,,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5c (GSM),,,,,,,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:24 AM",1,NoRegister,,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5c (GSM),,,,,,,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",1,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),54807,Home,,,,,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",2,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),54807,Home,,,,,
"Dec 27, 2014 05:23 AM",3,HomeTab,Which tab the user viewed ,1.4.0,iPhone,Apple iPhone 5s (GSM),54807,QuickAndEasy,,,,,
```

The code:

```
import csv


def printfields(keys, linesets):
    output_line = ""
    for key in keys:
        if key in linesets:
            output_line += linesets[key] + ","
        else:
            output_line += ","
    print output_line


def csvwriter(reader, path):
    """
    write reader to a csv file path
    """
    with open(path, "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        for line1 in line:
            if line1 in path:
                writer.writerow(line1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fields = [
        "UserID", "tabName", "RecipeID", "type", "searchWord", "isFromLabel", "targetUID"
    ]
    mappedLines = {}
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in reader:
            fieldPairs = [
                p for p in
                line['Params'].strip().strip('}').strip('{').strip().split(';')
                if p
            ]
            lineDict = {
                pair.split()[0].strip(): pair.split(':')[1].strip()
                for pair in fieldPairs
            }
            mappedLines[reader.line_num] = lineDict
        path = "output.csv"
        csvwriter(reader, path)

    for key in sorted(mappedLines.keys()):
        linesets = mappedLines[key]
        printfields(fields, linesets)
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. after `def` stmt you need to add indent. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is properly indented now.

Comment: Sample input? Desired output example?

Comment: This code doesn't run as well.  Fix the errors (`"wd"` isn't a valid string for `open`, indentation is still wrong after `if line1 in path` and missing `:`).

Comment: added input as well as output I'd to get. I think I fixed errors you mentioned. still don't run though

Comment: Your csv line ends in `,` this doesn't make sense

Comment: `with open(path, "r") as csv_file:` use `w` flag

Comment: Replaced to `w` flag

Comment: the `,` separates each parameter but some parameters are missing on a row level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code,

First take this to top of your file

```
fields = [
    "Timestamp","Session Index","Event","Description","Version","Platform","Device","User ID","Params",""
]
```

Use `DictWriter` to write `dict`.

```
def csv_writer(lines, path):
    """
    write reader to a csv file path
    """
    with open(path, "w") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        # Iterate over dict
        for line1, val in lines.iteritems():
            writer.writerow(val)
```

Use you mapping

```
        csv_writer(mappedLines, path)
```

Comment: Thanks! great help. However I still need to write the first 8 column to my newly created csv. not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

`csv_writer` references a symbol `line` -- this is not an argument to the function. How are you expecting that to be provided?

Comment: How are you expecting that to be provided? Sorry, I'm not sure to understand what you mean. I have remore the underscore in the function's name